# Connection errors occur when publishing with MS WebDeploy

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy, windows-server-2012, microsoft-web-deploy

For several months I have been using Web Deploy to publish ASP.NET Web Applications but for some days now, I more and more often receive different errors.

One of them says the "maximum amount of connections is exceeded":

> Fehler 5 Fehler des Webbereitstellungstasks. (Die maximale Anzahl zulässiger Verbindungen für   diese Website wurde überschritten.  Weitere Informationen unter: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEEDED_MAX_SITE_CONNECTIONS.)  0 0 Intranet

Sometimes a different kind of error occurs "Socketexception (10054)":

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4269,5): Warnung : Synchronisierung wird wiederholt, da ein Socketfehler (10054) aufgetreten ist.
>   1>Vorgang 'Serialization' wird für Objekt sitemanifest (sourcePath) erneut ausgeführt. Versuch 1 von 10.

While searching for a solution, i found some things like

[Can't get my EC2 Windows Server 2008 (Web stack) instance to receive publishings of my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841370/cant-get-my-ec2-windows-server-2008-web-stack-instance-to-receive-publishings)

I attempted to reset the certificate or skip the "https" in the URL for the Web-Deploy Server but I still receive the same errors.
Does anybody have a solution for it?

The Server is a Windows 2012 Server, i am using Visual Studio 2012 without updates. But I tried it also with Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 and VS 2013, and encountered the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

I just found and solved the problem by chance:

The problem occured because of a user-bandwidth limitation of my router. I found this by trying to publish a project with another PC (being in another network) which worked. So after some investigation I found and removed that limitation and the problem was solved, the WebDeploy publish is working again.

It seems the whole problem is a combination of that bandwidth limitation and maybe a bug in WebDeploy when the project to publish gets to big.
Some weeks ago, that project contained about 1500 files. Because of some additions that number increased to 3500 and the mentioned problem started to occur.