# VS to Azure Publish failure: Socket Error 10054

Tags: asp.net, sockets, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

I've seen a few posts around on this, none have solved my issue.

I'm trying to complete a web deploy to an Azure site but whilst updating the files I get warnings:

`MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4270,5) Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred
Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.`

In the web publishing wizard the connection can be successfully validated.

I saw mentioned somewhere that I should enable untrusted certificates, however I can't see this option in the web deploy settings in VS2013.

Important notes:

- I can deploy other projects (so I don't think it's a firewall issue).
- My colleague can perform the web deploy with an old version of my project (so Azure is working fine).
- I can't perform the web deploy using that same old version of the project.

It also doesn't work with an FTP publish either, although it doesn't give me the socket error warning. What could it be?

JK

Comment: I had the same problem and this [link][1] solved my problem


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841370/cant-get-my-ec2-windows-server-2008-web-stack-instance-to-receive-publishings

Comment: Thanks for the reply....I did see this and it hadn't helped unfortunately. The socket error 10054 is apparently so general it's impossible to diagnose properly without trawling through network traces. Microsoft support helped me diagnose it and my problem was something in my work buildings wifi which I don't have access to the traces of, so now I have to do any big publishes from home and small ones from the office.

Answer (score 20):

For any others who have this problem, I contacted Azure support and an engineer grabbed traces from their network end and mine to assess.

All he was able to deduce was that data packets were being intercepted somewhere between my machine and Azure's services resulting in timeout errors at both ends.

The problem lies with my work network, and I can successfully publish from other networks after testing...

Contact your network provider and have them investigate the issue, and in the mean time, if it is an option, make sure you test your publishing capability on other networks as it worked for me.

Comment: I had this as a result of something my ISP was doing. Tried on a different network and all worked fine. I know not everyone has multiple broadband connections to switch between but knowledge of this may help if you can't track down a cause for this issue.

Comment: In my case sometimes the Pubish works right away, sometimes a few retries needed, sometimes it errors out after 10 tries. Weird.

Comment: It feels like I encounter every extremely rare problem when working with Azure. Thank you. Switching router to another one (from different ISP) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old one.  But this might help someone.

For me it was the syncing processes for One Drive and Drop Box.  Once i paused all the syncing the issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you! I had gone through Azure SDK updates, countless threads, looked through lines of config files and wasn't getting anywhere. I disabled OneDrive syncing (business and personal) and then was immediately able to publish to an Azure Deployment slot once paused. In my case, I had unsynced changes that may have been the culprit.

Comment: Same here. Once I paused OneDrive syncing (business and personal), I was able to publish.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Our very similar problem with the same error message "Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred" turned out to be an Intrusion Prevention System (IPS)

Creating a exception rule on that fixed the issue.

Comment: That's interesting. I no longer have this issue. I never found a solution to it as the network team at the office I work in were very confused by it as well. I'll note this for any re-occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitively say that this is a network issue. I were having the exact same problem when publishing from VS 2015 to Azure Web Sites. Tried like 10 times w/o any luck. Disabled Windows Defender, no luck. Connected from a different network (through a VPN) and boom, everything was published fine.

Even if I disabled my local antivirus, I know the network guys have an appliance that "cleans" the traffic sent from the office, meaning that the traffic from my machine to Azure could be definitively being affected somehow. By connecting through a VPN, I skipped that.

Moral of the story: check your network, check your antivirus and check with your IT team if they have any device (Gateway antivirus, Intrusion Prevention Systems, Firewalls with funky rules, etc.) messing with your traffic.

Cheers

S

Comment: Checked all this.  Nothing wrong.  I'm in the complete dark with that.

Comment: Hosted a hotspot on my phone and the upload succeeded. I can recommend this as a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was an issue with the ISP, upload speed and stability was severely affected.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the answer in this thread, but this other thread seemed to have the answer that worked for me:
[Using WebDeploy (MSDeploy) to deploy to a Microsoft Azure Website target doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525972/using-webdeploy-msdeploy-to-deploy-to-a-microsoft-azure-website-target-doesnt)

The solution there was:

> Microsoft have pretty much confirmed it's a bug. They are struggling
>   to reproduce the issue though.
>
> The workaround is to put a new app setting into the Web app on the
>   Azure Portal, called WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM and set the value to
>   false. Deployment then works fine.

I did this, restarted the web app, reset the publish profile then redownloaded it and then it worked for me. I noticed that the URL they autopopulate to publish to was different and more random, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error occurred AFTER a slot swap and republish to original target slot.
Resolved by re-downloading target slot publish profile. 
Cause may be:
a) Slot swap affecting profile
b) Slot swap causing some behind the scenes processing that prevented publish for the period of time until I got the new profile

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the answer was even simpler: I had a version of the AngularJS v1.21 app running in Visual Studio through IIS Express. I had started it with . Once I "stopped all IIS Express Web Sites", the upload went as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues. Fixed mine by plugging Ethernet cable on my laptop. The wireless connection seems to be the cause of these issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error after I added some images and localization to my web site. I was wishing there was a way to find out which files were causing the connection to close.  So, I poked around and sure enough when selecting Publish in the Visual Studio the Publish page is displayed which includes the Azure App Service you are deploying to, the Site URL, Resource Group, etc. One of those items on that page is named "Preview"...clicking on it will allow you to preview the changes that will be made and choose which files to publish.

For me the retries started when a PNG image was being added, so I unchecked everything except for that image file and then clicked publish in the preview window.  It immediately started to retry.  So, I reduced the size of that image and converted it to a jpg which greatly reduced the size of the file.  I then went back to the preview window and tried just that new jpg image file and it worked.

I still got the retries after that when I tried to publish everything, so I unchecked everything except for the top 3 and published them...which went OK.  I then tried the next 3, etc. until I found that some java script files were also causing problems so I unchecked everything except for one of the java script files and just by itself it worked fine; however, the web site wouldn't work most likely because of references in that file which were in the other java script files.  But, after publishing all the java script files one at a time everything finally got published.

Also, please note that Microsoft apparently still has no clue; however, they have increased the retry count from 10 to 50.

Answer (score 0):

My issue seemed to be due to a new dependency only being compatible with x64 machines
the package was Emgu.CV
Updating file (\runtimes\win-x64\native\cvextern.dll).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps somebody, another random reason this seems to happen.

This occurs for me in visual studio 2022, if I also have visual studio 2019 open this occurs. Closing both and restarting 2022 resolves.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. When I faced this issue, my internet speed was 11Mbps and also the wireless,
I changed my internet connection and used my office internet connection which was 50+Mbps, and also the wired connection.
After that the error was gone and it was published in 2 minutes just. Previously it was taking 20 to 30 minutes and got this error and warning. I am still not sure that why it resolves the issue after changing the internet connection from slow to fast, but it works! just posting so that it might help some others.