# VS 2013 Web Deployment Failing - Socket Error 10054

Tags: sockets, azure, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, webdeploy

I posted on friday regarding this issue and received no response, however since then some updates have occurred which might affect whether people have an answer to my question or not.

I'm trying to deploy an MVC website to Azure, and in this particular project the web deploy receives a `Socket Error 10054` and gives up after 10 attempts saying it was `Unable to write data to the transport connection`. It makes varying progress in between the socket failures but never completes within the 10 attempts.

I have since had a play around with other projects which are deployed to different url locations within this same Azure Account and they deploy fine! I think this means the problem is not on my end, i.e. port 8172 is open and deployment can be achieved with my current local settings.

What are the problems that can cause this socket error 10054? I saw somewhere that I should enable the "Allow untrusted certificate" option when deploying but I can't find that option within VS 2013.

Any ideas are welcome please,
This issue is driving me mad, it seems there's a real mixed bag of solution ideas which have worked for others but not me.

JK

Comment: Rather than creating a new question, edit the [exiting one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696898) please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS 2013 Web Deploy failure: Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696898/vs-2013-web-deploy-failure-warning-retrying-the-sync-because-a-socket-error)

Comment: Sorry. Yes it is a duplicate I just reposted with new info. Edited the existing one.