# Open port 8172 on windows 7 - Telnet

Tags: sockets, port, telnet, webdeploy

I'm having trouble completing a web deploy from VS2013 as I posted in [VS to Azure Publish failure: Socket Error 10054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696898/vs-2013-web-deploy-failure-warning-retrying-the-sync-because-a-socket-error)

Apparently web deploy uses port 8172, which I cannot telnet to at the moment despite rules being present in my windows firewall allowing the port through.

I am using the commands `telnet localhost 8172` and `telnet 192.168.0.1 8172` and it says it cannot connect to the host on port 8172.

I'm not sure this is the issue because I can complete a web deploy to Azure in my other projects? But in any event I'm confused as to why I cannot telnet to the port.

Is my syntax wrong?

JK

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually have any service running on port 8172.  Try this resource: http://forums.iis.net/t/1088260.aspx?Port+8172+not+listening

Comment: As I understand MSDeploy should use the MsDeployAgentService which should be listening on that port. How would I find out which port was being listened on by that service? And surely as this MSDeploy process works with a different project (same service) should mean the port is open and my possibly isn't the port?

Comment: In windows OS you can use `netstat` command to see what is listening to whom on what port.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure you need to open up a port in the 'Network group' settings.

If you're using CloudFlare or some other kind of proxy, make sure to connect with the IP address of the VM or the MS supplied domain name and not your 'website domain name'. CloudFlare won't proxy through any old random port.